# Does the temperature of the body of an aircraft increases its efficiency?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft

I am actually working on a prototype of a Plane,

i was wondering if the temperature of the body of the plane can make the Plane more efficient,

if the structure is at 25°C needs less energy to maintain a steady state flight then a structure at -20°C ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think your title is asking something very different than the body of the question.  Do you want to recover energy from the excess heat, or are you asking if just being warmer makes it more efficient?

Comment: i have just edited the question thank you @JMac , does the temperature of the body (structure) makes the plane more efficient ?

Comment: Is there any reason you think it might change anything?

Comment: yes because when we increase the temperature of two materials in contact the friction decreases which leads to less losses, and when an aircraft is flying the outer temperature is -51°C with the pressure on the winds it can become -20°C which is still a very low temperature which mean dense air and more particules hitting the body, but this is my first analysis still can't have any scientific proof

Answer (score 0):

Planes in the real world undergo expansion as they heat up. Depending on design, heat may actually make them more efficient. The SR-71, for example, supposedly leaked while it was on the groundbecause its seals needed to account for 11 inches of length expansion due to heat.

Comment: i never knew that, the aircraft i am trying to design is solar powered, this expansion can cause serious problems to the wing and pv arrays on it

Answer (score 0):

No. The drag of an airfoil is not a function of its temperature.
[*Read this excellent e-book.*](https://www.av8n.com/how/)

Drag is categorized as that which is due to lift (induced drag) and everything else (parasitic drag).
To be the most efficient in steady flight, both of those need to be minimized.
The drag due to lift is minimized by wing design and choice of speed.
The parasitic drag is minimized by having smooth surfaces, etc.

Keep in mind that if drag is too low, the plane may not be able to get down easily, so it needs spoilers or air brakes to create extra drag, when needed.

Comment: thank you, but the model established for the drag does takes in consideration the wind parameter, which includes for instance the density o f the wind at the wing, and this density is a function of the temperature, now this is only one parameter, what about the material and the smoothness of the surface, the temperature should have some effect on that

Comment: @nkey: Density of the air is certainly a function of its temperature, but you shouldn't count on being able to heat or cool the air you're moving through. In any case that doesn't make it any more or less "slippery". Sure the smoothness is important - nothing kills lift like an almost-invisible layer of frost. On the cold side, cold is good because it makes air heavy, as long as it's not frosty or icy. On the hot side, beware the conditions high-hot-humid-heavy(plane). People get killed trying to take off in conditions like that.